# Change LinearLayout by screen dimensions

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am new to programming for Androids. I am seeking for any information about programming for Androids. Now I am wondering how to change -for example- buttons size considering of what is screen size.

As an example I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
    android:layout_marginRight="40px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And now I need this layout for a phone:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
android:layout_marginRight="40px"
```

but if there would be a tablet then I need

```
android:layout_marginLeft="200px"
android:layout_marginRight="200px"
```

How could I achieve this?

Also if you have bookmarked good tutorials on how to handle orientation please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to read up on ["Supporting multiple screens"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide from [android developers site](http://developer.android.com) and especially the section on ["Declaring Tablet Layouts"](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts).

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable not to use **px**, instead you should use **dp** i.e Density-independent Pixels.
For orientation support you should  declare separate layout xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
use dp instead of px for specifying margins and all.and try to use this in manifest file like this  <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
         />
```